# A nonzero injective module with no nonzero uniform submodule

Tags: injective-modules

Recall that a module $M_R$ is called **uniform** if the intersection of any two nonzero submodules of $M$ is nonzero. I need an example of a nonzero injective module with no nonzero uniform submodules. Indeed, the ring $R$ can not be right Noetherian because it 's well known that a nonzero injective module over a right Noetherian ring is the direct sum of nonzero uniform submodules.

Thanks for help. I appreciate if the details are included in the answer.

Comment: Pick your favourite ring R which is selfinjective, and has the property that right modules R and R^2 are isomorphic. Most explicit example is the quotient of endomorphisms of countably dimensional vector space by ideal of finite rank elements. Then subcategory generated by R under direct sums and summands is an abelian category that has no simple objects, and every object is projective+injective (even in ambient category of R-modules).